# Flutter run error: build failed at gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

````
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              6.4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1```

I tried ```flutter clean``` but it didn't work. I would really appreciate if someone helps me with this.
````